# Create relations in Yii automatically

Tags: php, yii, gii

I am newbie in **Yii** **framework**,

I am facing problem for **creating relations** in the model using **Gii**, I have already established foreign key with my tables in database but still automatic relations are not generated.

Any one knows how to solve the problem, if using an **extension**, please tell more about it.

Comment: Are you using mysql? If so how are you creating the foreign keys in your tables?

Comment: Yes, I am using mysql. For the foreign key as per simple constrain on_delete restrict and on_update cascade